# Could not enter data: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'UserID' when entering a new time sheet for a user with existing timesheet

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Cannot add a new time sheet for a user who already has an existing time sheet.  Otherwise the duplicate error message will appear.

```
INSERT INTO timesheet
( TimesheetID
, UserID
, DateCreated
, DateSubmitted
, TimesheetStatus
, TotalHours
, Comments
, ApprovedDate
, ApprovedBy
) VALUES 
( NULL
, 2
, '2017-04-12 00:00:00'
, '2017-04-29 00:00:00'
, 0
, 4
, 'new'
, '2017-04-20 00:00:00'
, 'Alan'
)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well do you have a unique constraint on that column?

Comment: Is it a primary key..if yes then remove it..it will solve your problem

Comment: Yes the timesheetId is the primary key and the foreign key for the table is the UserId  column. But the userId is a primary key for the user table .

Comment: in what table you are inserting ? provide some code because if it's a foreign key you can enter duplicated value are reinserting the user in your code?

Comment: There showed the existing table values and the insert statement.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the unique constraint on UserID. It should be a regular index, not a unique index.

Also you should probably convert the Comment column to an integer (TINYINT will do) and have it reference a table with possible states, instead of typing Rejected, Approved etc. for every row. It will take up way more storage and be more prone to errors or inconsistencies the way you're doing it now. The same goes for ApprovedBy. It should reference the UserID of the approving user.

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
INSERT INTO `timesheet` (`TimesheetID`, `UserID`, `DateCreated`, `DateSubmitted`, `TimesheetStatus`, `TotalHours`, `Comments`, `ApprovedDate`, `ApprovedBy`) VALUES (NULL, '2', '2017-04-12 00:00:00', '2017-04-29 00:00:00', '0', '4', 'new', '2017-04-20 00:00:00', 'Alan')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
/*maybe you need to delete that first `TimesheetID` = NULL if `TimesheetID` is  NOT NULL 
`TimesheetID` = NULL,*/
`UserID` = '2',
`DateCreated` = '2017-04-12 00:00:00',
`DateSubmitted` = '2017-04-29 00:00:00',
`TimesheetStatus` = '0',
`TotalHours` = '4',
`Comments` = 'new',
`ApprovedDate`= '2017-04-20 00:00:00',
`ApprovedBy` = 'Alan'
```